# Odoo Inherit - adding fields

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I am testing Odoo 9 and and trying to figure out the inheritance. With the below code should the field jason_test2,total_amount_invoice and total_balance_invoice  be added to the res.partner table. It is not adding them and I do not know if it should be.

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp import fields, models, api, exceptions, _
class ResPartner(models.Model):


_inherit = 'res.partner'
def _get_total_amount_invoice(self):
    res = {}
    for partner in self:
        invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
        invoice_ids = invoice_obj.search([('partner_id', '=', partner.id)])
        amount_total = 0
        for invoice in invoice_ids:
            amount_total += invoice.amount_total
        res.update({'total_amount_invoice': amount_total})


def _get_total_balance_invoice(self):
    res = {}
    for partner in self:
        invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
        invoice_ids = invoice_obj.search([('partner_id', '=', partner.id)])
        balance_total = 0
        for invoice in invoice_ids:
            balance_total += invoice.residual
        res.update({'total_balance_invoice': balance_total})


jason_test2 = fields.Char("Jason2")

total_amount_invoice = fields.Monetary(string='Amount Total', type='float',
                                       readonly=True, compute='_get_total_amount_invoice')
total_balance_invoice = fields.Monetary(string='Balance Total', type='float',
                                        readonly=True, compute='_get_total_balance_invoice')
```

Comment: Check whether you imported your new python file in __init__.py file

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is a question formatting issue, the body of your class definition should be indented, otherwise it is not part of the class at all.

```py
class ResPartner(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    def _get_total_amount_invoice(self):
        res = {}
        for partner in self:
            invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
            invoice_ids = invoice_obj.search([('partner_id', '=', partner.id)])
            amount_total = 0
            for invoice in invoice_ids:
                amount_total += invoice.amount_total
            res.update({'total_amount_invoice': amount_total})


    def _get_total_balance_invoice(self):
        res = {}
        for partner in self:
            invoice_obj = self.env['account.invoice']
            invoice_ids = invoice_obj.search([('partner_id', '=', partner.id)])
            balance_total = 0
            for invoice in invoice_ids:
                balance_total += invoice.residual
            res.update({'total_balance_invoice': balance_total})


    jason_test2 = fields.Char("Jason2")

    total_amount_invoice = fields.Monetary(string='Amount Total', type='float',
                                           readonly=True, compute='_get_total_amount_invoice')
    total_balance_invoice = fields.Monetary(string='Balance Total', type='float',
                                            readonly=True, compute='_get_total_balance_invoice')
```

Comment: Without indention problems should the jason_test2, total_amount_invoice and total_balance_invoice be added to the res.partner table. I

Comment: Just `jason_test2` should be added to the table. The other two are computed fields, which by default are not stored, unless you specify `store=True` in the field definition. Also ensure that you have imported your module in the `__init__`, as @Charif suggested and that you have installed/upgraded your module after the field definitions have changed.

Answer (score 0):

> The monetary field needs a complementary currency field to store the
>   currency for the amounts.

1 Add a field to store the currency that is being used

```
class LibraryBook(models.Model):
     # ...
     currency_id = fields.Many2one('res.currency', string='Currency')
```

2 Add Monetary field to store amount

```
total_amount_invoice = fields.Monetary(string='Amount Total', type='float',
                                   readonly=True, currency_field='currency_id' compute='_get_total_amount_invoice')
```